# Searching the database for a product name

Tags: php, sql, database

```
    <?php include "connect.php"; ?> <br /> <br />

<form action="" method="get">
    Search: <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $get = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE NAME = echo $_GET['search']");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
        echo $row['NAME']." ".$row['INFO'];
    }
?>
```

what im trying to do is once a user enters a name into the search bar and submits it i want to to search into the database... ive tried everything so please tell me a way of doing this please.

Comment: Do you want an exact search? case sensitve? or are you looking for a `LIKE` search?

Comment: Can you please formulate a clear question ? Nobody knows what you want

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$get = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Name LIKE '%" . $_GET['search'] . "%'");
```

***BUT!!!!***

*Beware of [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)*

I recommend using this method:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(<ServerAddress>,<DatabaseName>,<Password>,<UserName>)
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TableName WHERE Name LIKE") or die($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_params('s', "%" . $_GET['search'] . "%");
$stmt->execute() or die ($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_result($Col1, $Col2, $Col3);
while($stmt->fetch()):
    ...
endwhile;
```

There is obviously a lot more to the code here, but ultimately it is safer. Also this binds the columns to PHP variables which allows you to use them freely.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` should be satisfactory in regards to SQL injection, although your OOP approach is encouraged. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using $_GET, you should set $_GET['search'] equal to a variable instead of using "echo" in the middle of your query. However, I wouldn't pass the search through the URL with $_GET, because it's less secure. Try changing the form method to "post:"

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
  <label for="name">Search</label>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And then the "search.php" file on the backend would look something like this:

```
<?php
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['name']));

    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($run);

    foreach($item as $result){
      //echo the results how you will 
    }
?>
```